# What is the true story of Bender's origins?

Tags: futurama

In the episode "Lethal Inspection" it is shown that Bender was made in a factory in Mexico and approved by Hermes Conrad. However, throughout the series Bender makes references to his parents, such as saying his grandmother was a bulldozer and I believe he once said that his mother was a hoe.

In the episode the Bots and the Bees, we learned how robots are conceived. So how could Bender have been made by Mom in a Mexican factory yet have parents and grandparents?

Answer (score 3):

He indeed has said that his grandmother was a bulldozer. You can see it in the movie "The beast with a million backs":

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0xQtv-Mu7A

But in one episode he shows a text under his lid "Hecho en Mexico":

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6TjnZ64Rxo

This is just another one controversy about Bender. In [the Wikipedia profile of Bender Bending Rodriguez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_%28Futurama%29) it is stated:

> Bender, an industrial metalworking robot, was built in the year 2997 at Fábrica Robotica De La Madre, a manufacturing facility of Mom's Friendly Robot Company in Tijuana, Mexico. However, the story of his construction is a mystery. Although different creation processes have been shown, David X. Cohen has stated that the viewer has only been shown Bender emerging from the machine that created him, whilst what happened inside the machine has not yet been revealed. According to one version, suggested by a Hermes' flashback, and also by a reverse aging process shown in the "Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles" episode, a newborn Bender possessed a baby-like body. In "Bendless Love", however, Bender is portrayed with a normal, adult-sized body in a flashback sequence conveying his memory of coming into existence. As Bender's memory contains an adult form, the episode's content suggests that the character might actually be recalling a transfer to an adult body, rather than the moment of creation. An alternative view, considered by some viewers as the most provocative, was seen in the episode "Rebirth", in which it is proposed that Bender is actually a cyborg reconstructed from adult stem cells.

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question, although it does increase the validity of my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This question really is a hard one since we see [Bender](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender) in soo many scenarios getting "born" so we have the "*[Bendless Love](http://theinfosphere.org/Bendless_love)*" EP were we see him getting born in his regularly size in Tijuanam Mexico, Fábrica Robotica De La Madre, so we know where he was born.

We got more proof that Bender's mother really is that machine as seen in Bendless Love, we got EP "*[Xmas Story](http://theinfosphere.org/Xmas_Story)*" were we can see that Bender gets a card from his mother (the yellow arm robot that picks him together in EP Bendless Love).

In EP "*[Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles](http://theinfosphere.org/Teenage_Mutant_Leela%27s_Hurdles)*" they all get youthasized and they get younger by the minute and we there sees Bender getting back too his baby state.

And in this EP "*[Lethal Inspection](http://theinfosphere.org/Lethal_Inspection)*" we see [Hermes Conrad](http://theinfosphere.org/Hermes) as inspector 5 and baby Bender getting inspected by Hermes. They go to Mom's fabric in Mexico so we still now that he got born there.

And then there is also the EP "*[A Clockwork Origin](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clockwork_Origin)*" were Bender says that he is evolving and growing BUT [Prof. Farnsworth](http://theinfosphere.org/Farnsworth) says that robots got created quite recently. But later on in this EP we can see that robots can evolve (thanks to Prof. Farnsworth's who designed the [Nanobots](http://theinfosphere.org/Nanobots)). So from this we can make the conclusion that robots can evolve and that then they should also be able to grow up from baby robots (or evolve one might even say).

Then we have a fresh EP "*[The Bots and the Bees](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Bots_and_the_Bees)*" where Bender does the nasty with [Bev](http://theinfosphere.org/Bev) and they get a baby robot (not factory made) that grows up. So from these two last episodes we learn that there are robots that can grow older.

So too get some kind of summary of this can be kinda hard but as I see it Bender in EP Bendless Love says that he remembers his own birth and we see that little part, now I think that Bender remembers himself looking like that but he dosen't really see himself as a baby (when we grow up we don't really notice that we are changing and growing), so in the the EP Lethal Inspection what we see is a memory of Hermes and I think that this is how Bender looked like when he was "born" and one of those reasons is becouse of the EP Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles where they get age reversed and you see Bender get younger and younger. Bender even get's turned into a disc wich contains his blueprint, if I only knew who made that blueprint that would be the real origins (it was proboably Prof. Farnsworth)...

Comment: You could also explain all the contradictions by the fact that it's an (insanely awesome) cartoon and the writers were more concerned with comedy than consistency. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that he refers to the machine that built him as his mother, since factory machines count as robots. As for his grandmother being a bulldozer, I'm not sure.

Comment: if you can back your claim up with evidence from sources you can link to, you'll probly get some upvotes for your answer.

Comment: Didn't Bender say his mother was a hoe at some point?

Answer (score 1):

In Bendless Love, Bender recounts his birth four years prior. He was born in a factory in Tijuana, and his mother is shown to be a giant robotic arm. This story holds in several other episodes. In The Bots and the Bees, Bender tells his bastard son, Ben, that he's a great bender because he inherited his arm-control software from his mother. In the movie they showed Bender at the robot teen center, they said that in addition to being put together in a factory, robots could have babies to keep up with consumer demand. Bender was still made in a factory, it was his SON that was conceived by robots.

I haven't read any other theories, or if Futurama had a fix for this, but

**HERE IS MY THEORY TO FIX BENDER'S ADULT BIRTH AND BABY BIRTH:**

In Lethal Inspection, we see a young Hermes approving robots on an assembly line. Baby Bender comes along, and despite his being defective, Hermes still approves him. However, like I said before, we are shown Bender being born as a fully grown robot in Bendless Love just four years prior.

Look at how young Hermes looks in that flashback (or just Google "Bender baby"): http://pichars.org/store/6343_original_2Isi6.gif

Hermes Conrad was born in 2959, making him well over 50 by the time he and Bender go looking for Inspector 5. Let's say Hermes is 30 years old in this flashback, which would mean Bender was REALLY born over 20 years ago!

*So how is he born again in the Bendless Love flashblack?*

In Lethal Inspection, after the Sith War reenactment, Bender is telling everyone how he just uploads into a new bending unit body if he died in his own. What if Bender died in the body (or bodies) before the adult birth we saw four years ago? He would have uploaded into the Bender body that we all know and love.

*But he's defective and can't upload into a new body, that's the point.*

I know this part is a bit reaching, but that's why it's a theory. We know Bender's current body is defective and he will permanently die with it. However, we don't know that his original body was defective for that reason. It could have been another problem altogether, they don't tell you!