# Why was Bender made in a factory in Mexico but Ben wasn't factory made?

Tags: futurama

Why was Bender made in Mom's Mexican robot factory but Ben wasn't factory made?

I know that Bender was made in a factory in Mexico but why wasn't Ben? I thought all robots came from Mom's Friendly Robot Factory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the true story of Bender's origins?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19587/what-is-the-true-story-of-benders-origins)

Answer (score 8):

"Since factories can't manufacture enough robots to meet demand, robots can also reproduce by mating" As stated by the narrator of 'Sex Ed. Volume One' in the Episode '[The Bots and the Bees](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Bots_and_the_Bees)'.

"As Gerald's antennae uploads a binary file to Francine's internal drive, manufacturing specs are then merged by a randomised algorithm, and the resulting code guides the assembly of a new robot" Also stated by said narrator.

So there are two known ways of creating a new robot, 'Factory Construction' and 'Reproduction'.

Answer (score 1):

Not all robots are created by Momcorp - Momcorp was founded somewhere in 2900s, but many robots featured in the series predate that (e.g. [Robot Santa](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Robot_Santa_Claus)). Moreover, it appears not to be unusual for Bender to have offspring - besides Ben, he appears to have at least [two more sons](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Bender#Family) - firstborn, given to Robot Devil, and Junior, fathered with the Crushinator.

Comment: Junior is not Bender's son. It is revealed at the end of the episode that Billy is "just an innocent husband and father"